# How to deal with secrets in client side javascript apps that run only in the browser when following a build once deploy anywhere approach?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, nginx, environment-variables

I'm a back-end developer. I've done things with client side js frameworks but not too many.

I am configuring the CI/CD pipeline for a VueJs application that uses Vite, building a docker image with an nginx base image and serving the VueJs within it.

For example, assuming that I can create a `dist` folder out of the VueJs with

```
npm run build
```

then I could run the web app with a simple http web server such as

```
npm install -g http-server
cd dist
http-server
```

or copy the contents of `dist` into nginx when building a Docker image:

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In other words, the js web app does not require node as it's a bunch of html+css+js served by a web server that does not understand javascript.

I want to have the same approach as in the back-end: a **build once, deploy anywhere** therefore I want to be able to have the JS code rely on environment variables, and then decide at launch time which environment variable values to inject (i.e: when I spin up a container like `docker run -e MySetting=foo repo/front-end-app`).

I keep struggling to find a solution to that. If I try to access environment variables in OS from the VueJs app with `process.env` I get undefined, so I guess that's not the right approach when the javascript runs in the browser.

So I need a way to provide settings or secrets at server side, but that does not seem possible in my opinion, because the nginx server does not execute code, it simply serves static files.

How does people deal with this? Am I forced to have some process running in the server side under NodeJs and deploy the application as a NodeJs app so that I can protect secrets?

Otherwise, even if I was able to generate an `env` file on the fly when spinning up the docker container, that file would have to be served to the browser also, and the secrets (e.g: basic auth credentials, third party api key, etc.) would be exposed.

Hopefully someone can refer me to a good link to read about or clarify things, because I keep hitting a wall when googling. Thanks!

---

UDPDATE 1 2022-04-01: I had a look at this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/
and I'm still confused.

> ```
> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!
>
> Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.
> ```

I understand why is dangerous to include secrets in the app itself. But does that mean that there is no safe solution at all when using client side?

Comment: Your Docker image entrypoint could be a script that modifies the frontend files and adds environment data. There are no secrets in frontend code.

Comment: @jabaa true. But that would still be embedded in the JS itself and exposed. So how does people deal with basic auth credentials, for example, in front-end apps? Do they have some part running on server side in node js dealing with those secrets then? I have never thought of this, but now that I'm dealing with SPA and front-end stuff I'm seeing a huge issue in the front-end project I am dealing with and I'm gonna have to use OpenID or token base auth if I really need to avoid secrets in front-end completely. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no secret in frontend. The browser needs all data in clear text to evaluate it and the user has access to all this data.

Comment: As you already said, you will need a separate server that stores secrets like API keys. So to be clear, there just is no other option. This server can be quite small though

Comment: In general, to inject config data into a built client-side app, you can use fetch() to load a file from the server. But as has been said, to protect API keys and the like you need a server anyway.